# Intercept oauth2 callback

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to connect an `iOS` Swift app to an API, and I've experimented with `oauthswift`, `aerogear`, and `heimdallr`.

The flow is working fine, but the API itself doesn't have user-owned resources. All users have access to all resources. The API does, however, require OAuth2 to authenticate.

Is there a way to prevent a swift app from bouncing to Safari (or Safariwebview) and either avoiding the user login part or handling it with a workaround? I know this is sort of antithetical to oauth2, but there's no need (and actually it would be an impediment) for a single user to be logged in to this api.

Basically, I want the app to login on the backend for access to every user. I know this api has sdk's in Ruby, Python, and Node that do just that. So, how can I do this in Swift?

Here's my oauthswift code that successfully gets me in:

```
let yourEndpoint = ("https://www.awebsite.com/search/shows/a_show")
    let oauthswift = OAuth2Swift(
        consumerKey: "my key",
        consumerSecret: "my secret",
        authorizeUrl: "https://www.awebsite.com/oauth/authorize",
        accessTokenUrl: "https://www.awebsite.com/oauth/token",
        responseType: "token")

        let name = "sample_api_proj"


    oauthswift.authorizeWithCallbackURL( NSURL(string: "xxx:xxxx:xx:oauth:2.0:xxx")!, scope: "", state: "", success: {
        credential, response, parameters in
        self.showTokenAlert(name, credential: credential)

        let parameters =  Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
        oauthswift.client.get("https://www.awebsite.com/api/search/shows/ashow", parameters: parameters,
            success: {
                data, response in
                let jsonDict: AnyObject! = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: [])
                print(jsonDict)
            }, failure: { error in
                print(error)
        })
        }, failure: { error in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm returning to this to provide the answer that I ultimately found. I didn't realize there were different [types of oauth2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.4), and the type used to authorize an entire app is called 'client credentials.' Not all libraries/pods are designed for this type of oauth. The working solution I found was with [p2.OAuth2](https://github.com/p2/OAuth2).